# Document element click() method not triggering in ionic angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, dom, dom-events

I have an angular ionic cordova app where I'm trying to trigger the click of an input from another span (so that I can trigger the native datetime keyboard in cordova) .  However the click event doesn't seem to be triggered on the input field.  Looking at the debugger, the click function of the document element is not null, but doesn't seem to do anything when triggered from the span.  This works on a normal jsfiddle as commenters have noted, but when in an ionic environment, it doesn't - see this codepen

http://codepen.io/MonkeyBonkey/pen/OPmOrZ

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('whenPickerInput').click();">
  {{(when | amCalendar)}}
</span>

<input 
  onclick="alert('input clicked')" 
  id="whenPickerInput" 
  type="datetime-local" 
  ng-model="when" />
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/hapehpcn/

Comment: @tymeJV I tested too and works.

Comment: hmm must be something with the ionic enviroment, I'll try to set up a codepen or jsfiddle with the ionic libs loaded

Comment: try on this codepen http://codepen.io/MonkeyBonkey/pen/OPmOrZ

Comment: @PSL that seems to trigger the onclick alert but doesn't actually trigger the native click behavior that I want - to pull up the native datepicker in mobile.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey How do you open the datepicker?

Comment: @PSL the datepicker opens automatically on mobile devices because the input type is datetime-local.  Figured out that ionic has a tap system that is interfering, answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so it looks like ionic has it's own click handler that removes the 300ms delay in mobile.  I have to remove that tap system for the input so that I can trigger the click event

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/

```
<input data-tap-disabled="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks - you're my hero today!

Answer (score 0):

You found a solution  with `<input data-tap-disabled="true" />` 
But better will be to change your code and don't use onclick. In Angular/Ionic  u can use ng-click.

Comment: sure, ng-click or onclick will both work - and ng-click is what I used in my final solution.  I wanted to use onclick in the example to better isolate the problem